# Is it necessary to close jdbc connection in localhost

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I use static methods in a java project that i build, to make queries to a localhost mysql db.

Something like that:

```
public static void sqlQuery() {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(localhost,root,password);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Some SQL);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Error Handling
    } finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    }
}
```

My Question is if i can keep the conn variable without close it and reuse it again for another query.

No other app use this db and i can do that i want with only 1 connection..

P.S. Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Yes, **but** doing so consumes resources on your database and there are limits to the maximum number of open connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections are not thread-safe, so using only one is fraught with peril.You should use a connection pool, with a new logical connection for each logical activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse a connection in the same context. Once you have changed your context, you should close the former connection and reopen another connection.

Comment: Define 'context'. You haven't mentioned thread safety. Answer is just waffle really.

Answer (score 0):

You should always close resources like JDBC connection. If you don't close them, it creates a [resource leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak) and it can slow down your program.

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to close the connection, since its not a thread safe. It is also not advisable to keep the connection object as the singleton.